# Auto scripting two folders with the same name, but 1 folder appended with a prefix

Tags: macos, unix, applescript, automator

I’m new to the forum and relatively new to scripting and wanted to ask a question.

I’m trying to script a workflow where when prompted, users create a folder and when the script executes, a dialogue pops up. Users name the folder, for example; NewFolder1, it is then saved in a directory. Another folder is then created in the background, into another directory with the same name created by the user earlier, but appended with a prefix, for example; Name_ NewFolder1.

I then want sub folders created in each directory as well as alias folders which point to Name_ NewFolder1 created in the original (NewFolder1) directory

I'm on a mac and I can do most of this via applescript or automator but am stuck on the initial creating 'NewFolder1' and 'Name_ NewFolder1' at the same time in the two separate directories.

I only want to prompt the user to name one folder rather than show them two dialogues for 'NewFolder1' and 'Name_ NewFolder1'

Does anyone have any ideas of how i can achieve this? Either via a shell, applescript or UNIX

Thank you

Comment: I think I was fairly precise with the question. khagler gave me an answer.

Comment: You were fairly precise with the requirements of the script you wanted someone to write for you. [3. "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do the part you're stuck on in AppleScript:

```
set folder_name to text returned of (display dialog "What is the folder name?" default answer "untitled")

set second_name to "Name_" & folder_name

tell application "Finder"
    make new folder at desktop with properties {name:folder_name}
    make new folder at desktop with properties {name:second_name}
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you for your rely, that is very helpful. How would i incorporate that into an automator workflow? In that, how would I add variables to each {name:folder_name}, {name:second_name}?  For example, the folder_name is created as 'Client1' I would like to add a variable to 'Client1' so that I could then create sub folders in that directory.

Comment: hi khagler. thanks again. How would I add variables to {name:folder_name} and {name:second_name} in order to create sub folders in these directories? Also adding variables to folders in order to create an alias from that folder. Thanks.

Comment: The `make new folder` command returns the folder it creates. In my example I ignored it, but you could capture it with `set first_folder to make new folder...`. You can then use `first_folder` as the location parameter to create a subfolder. (You could also do it all on one line with no variable, but that gets hard to read.)

Comment: Thanks, I'm using... `set new to make new folder at loc1 with properties {name:new_name}
make new folder at new with properties {name:"folder1"}`
This is for folder_name in the above example, but i need to create folders in second_name

Comment: could i use `set loc3 to ":path3:clientmedia_name"` then make new in loc3?

Answer (score 0):

`set client_name to text returned of (display dialog "Create Folders:" default answer "Type here")
set loc1 to ":path1"
set loc2 to ":path2"

set clientmedia_name to "name_" & client_name

tell application "Finder"
    make new folder at loc2 with properties {name:clientmedia_name}

```
set new to make new folder at loc1 with properties {name:client_name}
make new folder at new with properties {name:"1"}
make new folder at new with properties {name:"2"}
make new folder at new with properties {name:"3"}
make new folder at new with properties {name:"4"}
```

end tell`

This is how far i have got, but can't seem to create folders in the clientmedia_name dir

Thanks,